# Projection Valued Measure Question - Related to Spectral Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $E$ is a projection valued (spectral) measure from the complex plane into the projections on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and suppose that $E$ has compact support $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.  If one considers the normal operator $\int_K z dE(z)$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, what is the spectrum of this normal operator?

Comment: This seems like a homework problem that is just transcribed. What work have you done? Where are you stuck so that we can hint you in the right direction?

Comment: It may be a homework question somewhere, but I am not doing this for homework.  The motivation for this question is that if you have a normal operator of the form $\int_K z dE(z)$ for some compact set $K$ which is the support of $E$, I want to know if the projection valued measure that you get by applying the spectral theorem is actually the same $E$.  I think I have been able to show that if $\lambda$ is not in $K$ then it is not in the spectrum.  However, I don't know if the spectrum is all of $K$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258572/spectral-measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spectrum is $K$. If $\lambda\not\in K$, then the function $z\mapsto (z-\lambda)^{-1}$ is well-defined and bounded on $K$. Then
$$
\int_K\frac1{z-\lambda}\,dE(z)
$$
is the inverse of $\int_K(z-\lambda)\,dE(z)$, and so  every element not in $K$ is in the resolvent of the operator.

For the converse, I need to use a little technology (not saying that there isn't a more direct argument, but it doesn't spring to mind right now). The C* algebra $A$ generated by $\int_KzdE(z)$ equals the set of functions $\int_Kf(z)dE(z)$ for $f$ continuous. If $\int_K(z-\lambda)dE(z)$ is invertible, then its inverse is in $A$. That is, we have
$$
\int_Kf(z)\,(z-\lambda)\,dE(z)=I
$$
for some continuous function $f$. Now, if $\lambda\in K$, let $k$ such that $|f(z)|<k$ for all $z\in K$ and fix $\varepsilon=1/2k$; let  $P$ be the projection $$P=\int_{B_\varepsilon(\lambda)}1dE(z)=\int_K1_{B_\varepsilon(\lambda)}(z)\,dE(z),$$where $B_\varepsilon(\lambda)$ is the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $\lambda$.
Then
$$
P=P\,I=P\int_Kf(z)\,(z-\lambda)\,dE(z)=\int_{B_{\varepsilon(\lambda)}}f(z)\,(z-\lambda)\,dE(z),
$$
and
$$
1=\|P\|=\left\|\int_{B_\varepsilon(\lambda)}f(z)\,(z-\lambda)\,dE(z)\right\|\leq\varepsilon \,k<\frac12,
$$
a contradiction. The conclusion is that the function $f$ cannot exist; that is, that $\int_K(z-\lambda)\,dE(z)$ is not invertible if $\lambda\in K$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this question!! I really appreciate your detailed answer.  I was thinking the spectrum was $K$ but didn't know how to prove the 'converse'.